# Unable to start or call boot completed broadcast receiver after reboot android MI-4i

Tags: android

//AndroidManifest.xml file code

//permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

// receiver

```
 <receiver android:name="app.EasyLogger.receivers.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

---

//BroadCast Receiver class

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "BootCompletedReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context foContext, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:BootCompletedReceiver called");
    }
}
```

// log file not printed or also same for toast message

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they have a whitelist, you have to be in the whitelist to receive BOOT_COMPLETED events.